# How to convert a div to a canvas using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

[xCharts JS](http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/) uses some CSS classes that are converted to a HTML 5 canvas once the Javascript is interpreted.

I was wondering if ReactJS knows how to handle such type of component?

When I write the `<div>` containing the class for canvas conversion inside the render method, React return a `<div>` and not a canvas containing a chart.

Here is the code:

```
render: function(){
  if (!this.state.data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return(
    <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
      <div className="smallstat box">
        <div className="boxchart-overlay red">
       <!-- the div underneath should convert to a canvas --> 
      <div classname="boxchart">5,6,7,2,0,4,2,4,8,2,3,3,2</div>

        </div>  
        <span className="title">Transactions</span>
        <span className="value">{this.state.data.globalPNL}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is the expected result for that `<div>`

```
<canvas class="flot-overlay" 
   style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 619px; height: 300px;" 
   width="1238" height="600">
</canvas>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [xChart docs](http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/docs/) you need to make a call to initialize the chart:

```
var myChart = new xChart('bar', data, '#myChart');
```

If you're already doing this, have you verified that the element exists in the DOM at the point in time the chart is being initialized? You might try initializing the chart in [componentDidUpdate](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate)